# Ajax With ReactJS to NodeJS

Tags: ajax, node.js, reactjs

I'm using webpack-dev-server while developing in ReactJS.
I also want to add a backend which will be written in NodeJS.
When I run the webpack-dev-server it binds to port 8080.
When I run node, it can't bind to the same port.
Therefore, I'm unable to perform $.ajax requests due to the SOP.
How do I get over this issue?

NodeJS:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/messages', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world!');
});

let server = app.listen(8081, function() {
  const host = server.address().address;
  const port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

React/JS/Ajax:

```
$.getJSON('/messages', function(data) {
  this.setState({
    messages: data
  });
}.bind(this));
```

And I'm running `webpack-dev-server` without any parameters.

Comment: How are you binding to a port on your nodejs code? Can you show some code?

Comment: @FelipeSabino Edited

Comment: what about the `webpack-dev-server` port bind?

Comment: @FelipeSabino I left it untouched.

Comment: Can you show what you are doing there? And also how you call it?

Comment: @FelipeSabino That's basically what I'm doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `port` of app is different from the `port`of your server. if you want to keep save port, you can try to use webpack proxy

```
module.exports = {
    // the other config of your webpack
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallBack: true,

        proxy: {
            '/message': {
               target: 'http://localhost:8081',
               secure: false,
               changeOrigin: true
            },

        },
    },
}
```

when you fetch `http://localhost:8080/messages`, webpack-dev-server will proxy to `http://localhost:8080/messages`.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is on port 8080.

Your server is on 8081.

If you want to request from the server, you need to specify the port to the server. If not, it will request to the port your app is running to, which is 8080.

```
$.getJSON('https://localhost:8081/messages', function(data) {
  this.setState({
    messages: data
  });
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: That is exactly the problem. Since I'm using two different ports, Same Origin Policy causing it to not work.